# Add existing Object to an array and show it on the view(2way binding)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to add an Ingridient  to a recipe, here is what I tried.

Markup:

```
   <div class="container " *ngFor="let rec of UI_Recipes" [class.active]="rec === selectedRecipe">


          <div *ngFor="let iu of rec.ingridientUnits; let i = index;">
            <p>{{iu.ingridientID}}</p>
            <p>{{iu.unitID}}</p>
            <p>{{iu.amount}}</p>
          </div>

          <!--[disabled]="!new_unit_input"-->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onIngridientUnitAdd(rec.id)">Add Row</button>
```

Typecript:

```
onIngridientUnitAdd(recId) {
    let a = new IngridientUnit();
    a.ingridientId = 'e';

    console.log(a);

    this.UI_Recipes.filter(x => x.id === recId)[0].ingridientUnits.push(a);
    // Is there a better (angular) way, to add an Object ?!

}
```

What I get?

=> on the view I just get "0"s, instead of the entire Object.

what should I do(maybe a more angular way), do you need anything more  ?

using angular 8

Comment: How does your output look exactly? And how exactly is `UI_Recipies` structured ?

Comment: I created a sample [app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lcnyvd). It works fine. What is exactly the problem?

Comment: I don't get any Zeros in your example when adding an ingridient. To your other question, you could try to pass the recipe to your `onIngridientUnitAdd` method and not just the id, than you would add directly to the ingridients. Not sure if the value in the array is changed tho.